# How i can compare to which nesting enum associated my value

Tags: swift, enums

this is my code

```
public enum Key {
   enum A: String {
        case x
   }
   enum B: String {
        case y
   }
   enum C: String {
        case z
   }
}
```

Now I need to compare to which nesting enum the argument belongs,
it is possible something like this?

```
func readString(key: Key) {
   switch key {
      case .A:
         //do smth
      default:
         break
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `Key` is an empty enum which only provides a "namespace" for the inner types. You cannot even create a value of type `Key`. – Can you given an example how you would call the `readString` function?

Comment: Now I use some functions, and for determinate in what space I am submitting arguments like this `readString(key: Key.A) readString(key: Key.B) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to specifically my problem:

```
enum Key {
    case a(A)
    case b(B)
    case c(C)

    enum A: String {
        case x
    }
    enum B: String {
        case y
    }
    enum C: String {
        case z
    }
}
```

After this we can use switch-case.

But it will be better to do in the following way:

1. Creating protocol
2. Subscribe
3. Call this in generic

Something like this

```
protocol CKey: RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    var nestingEnum: String { get }
}

enum Key {
    enum A: String, CKey {
        case x
        var nestingEnum: String {
            return "X"
        }
    }
    enum B: String, CKey {
        case y
        var nestingEnum: String {
            return "Y"
        }
    }
    enum C: String, CKey {
        case z
        var nestingEnum: String {
            return "Z"
        }
    }
}
```

And call this

```
func read<Item: CKey>(for key: Item) -> String {
    //now we can read key.nestingEnum
}
```